# Comparing 2 strings in Java

Tags: java, string

I have two `String`s, for example:

```
s1=abcd
s2=abfg
```

I want to compare these two `String`s and print the starting `String` until they are different. For instance, I want to print `ab` in this case. How can I get this result?

Comment: convert into char arrays and loop

Comment: Look into `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils` class with tons of useful `String` methods

Comment: @IvanPronin specifically what are you talking about?

Comment: You can loop without having to convert to char arrays.  Just use a for loop that goes up to the length of the shortest String, and then use the charAt() method on the String class.

Comment: E.g. [indexOfDifference](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#indexOfDifference-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-)

Comment: This has been asked several times before. Search for "longest common prefix".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @IvanPronin mentioned, If you do this very frequently you can use the  **indexOfDifference** of **StringUtils**:

```
String s1 = "abcf";
String s2 = "abdf";
System.out.println(s1.substring(0, StringUtils.indexOfDifference(s1, s2)));
```

but you have to download the jar and include it. [Download link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommonlang3jar.htm)

Answer (score 1):

```
package simple;

public class Simple {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "abcf";
        String s2 = "abdf";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int k = s1.length() < s2.length() ? s1.length() : s2.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            if (s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(i)) {
                sb.append(s1.charAt(i));
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(sb);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring(int startIndex, int endIndex) to split the strings from every position,

```
String s1 = "abcd";
String s2 = "abfg";
List<String> stringlist = new ArrayList<String>();

String shortest = null;
if(s1.length() <= s2.length()){
    shortest = s2;
}

for(int i = 1 ; i<shortest.length() ; i++){
    if(s1.substring(0,i).equals(s2.substring(0,i))){
        stringlist.add(s1.substring(0,i));
    }
}

System.out.println(stringlist.get(stringlist.size()-1));
```